# creating a 3d array in python does not create array correctly

Tags: python, arrays, 3d

I wish to make a 3d array by appending each element to the array in a loop, but instead of getting a 3d array I just get a 1d array with more elements in it. I'm working in Python 2.7

I want to get `labels = [1,34,u'te],[2,44,u've],[4,43,u'ht]`

My code so far is:

```
labels = []
for line in lines:
    lab = [h/100, maxf, title]
    labels = np.append(labels,lab)
```

but from this code I get:

```
labels = [u'1' u'34' u'te u'2' u'44' u've u'4' u'43' u'ht]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is a 2D *list* you are trying to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `labels.append` instead of `numpy.append`

Example code -

```
labels = []
for line in lines:
    lab = [h/100, maxf, title]
    labels.append(lab)
```

Also this would create the `labels` list as - `[[1,34,u'te],[2,44,u've],[4,43,u'ht]]`

`[1,34,u'te],[2,44,u've],[4,43,u'ht]` is not possible in python, these are either three different lists, or they are enclosed by another list as shown above (or a tuple, etc)